# nagivator.share get source of origin website from headers

Tags: javascript, navigator, web-share

Can we get the nagivator.share's source origin website/domain.
i.e., from where i am getting this request.
May be from the http headers.
So if i shared a text from site A to a pwa app B, I need to get site A from code.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible due to privacy reasons. Share operations are not traceable to their origin.